# Issue in API Calling with Routes

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, websocket

Can anyone solve my issue. I am working on a project where the ESP needs to call an URL and make a continuous connection using Web Socket to share the data. I made Routes for that and I used that in index.js but I am encountering some issue while calling that route.

```
// ./Routes/data.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// WebSocket endpoint for updating electricity usage data
router.post('/update', async (req, res) => {

      // Your code to handle the POST request
      const { userId } = req.query;
      const { message } = req.body;
      console.log(`Received message "${message}" for user ID: ${userId}`);

      // Your logic to process the data...

      res.status(200).send('Data received successfully');
});

module.exports = router;


// ./index.js
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const updateDataRoute = require('./Routes/data');


connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const port = 5000


app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json());

//Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./Routes/auth'));
app.use('/update', updateDataRoute);

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`smartMeter - BackEnd listening on http://127.0.0.1:${port}`)
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
      ws.on('message', (message) => {
            console.log('Received Message:', message);
      });
      ws.send("Connected to WebSocket")
})
```

When I am sending POST request to "http://localhost:5000/update" with a JSON in body {"message":"Hello","userId":"123"} from query I am getting this error. How to fix this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /update</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to make a connection between ESP and my database for that I thought that I'll send the ObjectId of user given by MongoDb in req query parameter and message in req body (Just to check wether everything is fine or not). But when it didn't work I tried sending ObjectId too in body but nothing worked

Comment: What is ESP? microcontroller esp32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

`app.use( updateDataRoute);`

because   updateDataRoute has already `/update`

so basicly `app.use('/update', updateDataRoute);` meant `/update/update`